Data truncation: Data too long for column 'params' at row 7
In my project I was using old Java and Spring version, so I had to update them. I've also updated some old dependencies.
Now when I start to run the application I got this error:

Error executing DDL "alter table activity_log modify column params
tinytext" via JDBC [Data truncation: Data too long for column 'params'
at row 7]

This error applies to all entities where I'm using the @Lob annotation.
Here is one of the classes:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class ActivityLog extends AdditionalAbstractAuditable<Long> {

    private String eventName;

    @Lob
    private String params;

    @Embedded
    private ActivityParamsId activityParamsId;
}

What could be the solution?

What database are you using? Also what is the data type in activity_log. params column?

The database is MySQL and the data type is longtext

Change:
@Lob
private String params;

Into:
@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
private String params;

